# Angular - Add Option to Select on Button Click

Tags: html, angular, typescript

On my current Angular page I have a select `dropdown` which is `autopopulated` with addresses that currently exists for a client, with the final option being "Add New Address". When this is clicked, a modal window is shown where a new address can be entered. When the address is saved it should be added to the dropdown and selected by default.

Currently this is the method that is executed when the new address is saved:

```
addressSubmitted(form: FormGroup) {
  if (form.valid) {
    var addressLine1 = form.controls['address'].value;
    var addressLine2 = form.controls['address2'].value;
    addressLine2 = addressLine2.trim();
    var city = form.controls['city'].value;
    var stateId = form.controls['state'].value;
    var state = this.SelectedState; //form.controls['state'].find()
    var postalCode = form.controls['zip'].value;

    var fullAddress = addressLine1 + ', ';
    if ('' != addressLine2) {
      fullAddress = fullAddress + addressLine2 + ', ';
    }
    fullAddress = fullAddress + city + ', ' + state + ' ' + postalCode
      --> this.popupForm.controls['address_select'].xxxx;
  } else {
    this.servicePNotify.error("Error", "New address information is not complete");
    this.service.validateAllFormFields(form);
  }
}
```

The `dropdown` in the `popupForm` form is named `address_select` and is the control that should have the new address added.

I've searched online but haven't been able to find anything that worked. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the options for `address_select` are generated in an `*ngFor` loop, just push the new address into the array that generates the options. Otherwise, you'll need to manually modify the DOM to add an `option` element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the value say as the input field you can set the value using either patch value or set value.I guess this takes care of the selecting it by default.
Now to take care of the dropdown what you can do is add to the list which populates the dropdown and if you want to show a selected CSS change then you can style the option based on the selected value from the input field.

This can help you with setting.

https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-2-form-controls-patch-value-set-value